# DISTINCT and AVG in mysql query

Tags: mysql, database, average

I have this mysql query:

```
SELECT round(AVG(DISTINCT points),0) as PM
FROM data
WHERE points != 0
```

In data db I have several users belonging to a different districts. Every user can be in as many districts as they want, but the points for every district is the same, so, we can have:

```
User , District , Points
   1 ,        1 ,     20 
   1 ,        3 ,     20 
   1 ,       21 ,     20 
   2 ,        3 ,     10
   2 ,        7 ,     10
```

I would like to extract the Average of points of the table above but only counting every user once regardless of how many districts he is in.

With my query I only get those with different points, but, for example, if I would have a User 3 with 10 points, the query will return: 15 (20+10 = 30/2 = 15), instead of the correct value: 13 (20+10+10 = 40 / 3 = 13,3333).

Any help, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Hi Strawberry...what are you missing? What do you need to try to help me? Let me know and I can provide it. I think that everything needed was provided. Thanks.

Comment: You should probably consider refactoring your table structure. If each user has the exact same points for every district they are in, `(user, points)` and `(user, district)` should be a separate tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Firstly, get the points for each user in a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), using `group by`.
- Now, using the derived table, compute the Average. You don't need to use `Distinct` now.

Try (assuming user is denoted by column `user_id` - change it if different):

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(`dt`.`user_points`),0) as PM 
FROM 
(
  SELECT `user_id`, 
         MAX(`points`) AS `user_points`  
  FROM `data`
  WHERE `points` != 0 
  GROUP BY `user_id` 
) AS `dt`
```

Comment: Trying this query I get the following error: The column dt.points in field list is unknown

Comment: @saysmus you should not be getting that error. Anyways I have updated the answer, please check again

Comment: @saysmus I have `user_id` as the column name for the user. Please change that accordingly to your database.

Comment: Thank you so much  @Madhur Bhaiya, this is working perfect! Thanks!!

Comment: @saysmus happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `GROUP BY` on the end of your query?

[Working Online Sample Demo at SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7aa017/1)

Build schema...

```
CREATE TABLE UserPoints (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Userid INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  Districtid INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PointsCount INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Insert some sample data...

```
INSERT INTO UserPoints (Userid, Districtid, PointsCount) VALUES (1, 1, 10);
INSERT INTO UserPoints (Userid, Districtid, PointsCount) VALUES (1, 2, 20);
INSERT INTO UserPoints (Userid, Districtid, PointsCount) VALUES (2, 1, 12);
```

Then select with GROUP BY...

```
SELECT Userid, AVG(PointsCount) FROM UserPoints GROUP BY Userid;
```

Results...

```
Userid  AVG(PointsCount)
1       15
2       12
```

Comment: Hi @HoldOffHunger, thanks a lot for taking your time. That is not what I need. I need the average points for the whole table, not per user. I can get those values easily too.